# Related Product text is too high under product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi stack i have one weird problem with my custom coded template for my [WooCommerce site](http://www.manifestyourself.com/product/2017-power-session/). The text "Related Products" suddenly move too high,and now stock too high into product page.

[image]

I found in CSS that this class control that:

```
class="related products"
```

but dont know what to modify to move H2 text a little down under image from product. Any tip ?

Comment: I dont have this, so you have surely correct it…

Comment: yes i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it:

Via FTP download the related.php file located in the woocommerce plugin folder at:

woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php

Open the file using TextEdit (Mac) or your favorite editor for Win or Mac and change the following:

```
<section class="related products">

<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

<?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>
```

To the following:

```
<section class="related products">

<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2><br />

<?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>
```